# Cosmos Graph DB: How to resolve ConnectionPoolBusyException

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, connection-pooling, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

I am using .Net Gremlin SDK(Gremlin.Net 3.4.8) to query Cosmos DB. Very often I am getting error ConnectionPoolBusyException: All 1 connections have reached their MaxInProcessPerConnection limit of 1. Consider increasing either the PoolSize or the MaxInProcessPerConnection limit. I have configured the pool size to 1 and the MaxInProcessPerConnection to 1.

One request to my service is doing five different DB operations and no async tasks are performed. I would like to know if all the five DB operations are performed in the synchronous way then why getting ConnectionPoolBusyException. Also, is there any way to know the connections usage and the number of request in flight per connection.

Comment: Any specific reason behind limiting the pool size to 1? If you do not set it, it defaults to a value of 4. Same with MaxInProcessPerConnection, why is it limited to 1 when the default is 32?

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using to run the DB operations?